# Django: WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user' on some pages?

Tags: python, django, wsgi, django-middleware

I want to set a cookie if user is logged in or not.

**My middleware:**

```
class UserStatus(object):
    def process_response(self,request,response):
        user_status = 1 if request.user.is_authenticated() else 0
        max_age = (20)*52*7*24*60*60 # 20 years (After expiry, cookie gets deleted)
        response.set_cookie(user_status_cookie,user_status,max_age)
        return response
```

Added to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py at the end.

**Problem:**

- Error: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
- Why, when I have the Authentication and the Session middlewares active already ?
- Also, some pages are working smooth where as some are giving this error.
- What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the FineManual:

> During the response phases (process_response() and process_exception() middleware), the classes are applied in reverse order, from the bottom up

So I'd say you'd better add your middleware *before* the auth and session middlewares (assuming it only processes the response).

This being said, I'm a bit puzzled by the fact that you only have the error on some pages ???

Comment: I guess the some pages are not appended with the trailing slash.

Answer (score 25):

Ran into the same issue recently, and found that it happened when a url is being accessed without the trailing slash, and the APPEND_SLASH setting is set to true:

---

**Django processes initial request**

- CommonMiddleware.process_request

  - Redirects to newurl, which has the trailing slash
- process_response is still run in custom middleware

  - request.user is not present
- HTTP 301

**Django then processes the request of url with trailing slash**

- process_response is run in custom middleware

  - request.user is now present

---

Anyone knows why some of the main attributes (user and session) are not accessible in process_response after a permanent redirect?

Comment: Regarding why: It's because CommonMiddleware returned an `HttpResponse` value before `AuthenticationMiddleware.process_request` had a chance to run, which preempts `AuthenticationMiddleware`. "If it returns an HttpResponse object, Django won’t bother calling any other request, view or exception middleware, or the appropriate view; it’ll apply response middleware to that HttpResponse, and return the result." —https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/middleware/#process-request

Answer (score 17):

So it has to do with `APPEND_SLASH` being applied with via a redirect by Django Common Middleware, preventing the `process_request()` in `AuthenticationMiddleware` (which adds the `user` attribute) from being run but your `process_response` still being run.

Here's how Django Process Middleware ACTUALLY Works (from `django/core/handlers/base.py` in Django 1.6)

1. You request a URL that does not have a trailing slash. So `yourdomain.com/view`. This starts the middleware flow.
2. Once the request reaches `CommonMiddleware`, the middleware sees that there is not a slash and returns a `http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(newurl)`. This immediately stops any additional `process_requests` from being run, including one in `AuthenticationMiddleware` that add the `user` attribute to `request`
3. Because `CommonMiddleware` did not return an exception (including `Http404`), `django` will  now take the response from the middleware and run it through EVERY `process_response()` in EVERY middleware listed in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, no matter if that middleware's `process_request()` had a chance to run.

The only real way to fix this is to either move your code into a `process_request()` method located after `AuthenticationMiddleware` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` or detect via `hasattr()` if the `request` object has a `user` attribute.

Comment: This is great! My app worked once I put the middleware in this order: ('django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'MyMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware')

Answer (score 9):

do you have active this middleware?:

```
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'
```

And this middleware run before your middleware?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, some of my pages dont have the user in the request so in my middleware I do a quick check

```
if not hasattr(request, 'user'):
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be an exception raised within some middleware or any other code that runs before the django's AuthenticationMiddleware (which is responsible for assigning the .user to request object).

Then there will be an AttributeError upon accessing the .user variable.

For example, any exception triggered before the AuthenticationMiddleware had a chance to run might cause the error view to execute. You'll get the error as mentioned in the title of the question, if the error view depends on request.user.