# Django 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'

Tags: django, django-middleware

I keep on getting this exception when I do `request.set_cookie()` in the `process_view` of a custom middleware class. Here is the order of middleware classes in my settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'website.middleware.UserLastActiveMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `set_cookie()` call from `response` object.
Example:

> ```
> def process_response(self, request, response):
>     ...
>     response.set_cookie('user_agreement', user_agreement, domain='.mysite.com')
>     return response
> ```

Comment: Now I have a new exception: `NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'`. However, in my view I have `return self.render_to_response(context)`. What could it be?

Comment: Where you it use, middleware or `views.py`?

Comment: I'm trying to set the cookie in the middleware. In `views.py` I have a class based view with a TemplateResponseMixin and so the `get` function of the view returns `self.render_to_response(context)`.

Comment: It's already another problem instead this question. But it seems you wrong calling `render_to_response(template_name[, dictionary][, context_instance][, content_type])`

Answer (score 4):

To start off with, [`set_cookie()` is a method of `HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie), not `HttpRequest`, as you set cookies in your response to a requests.

Secondly, your middleware should come after `AuthenticationMiddleware`, since presumably it has to do with users.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this question: [Django: WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user' on some pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223597/django-wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-user-on-some-pages)

This problem usually occurs when you do not add the trailing slash because then a redirect is done to the url containing a trailing slash