# WSGIRequest object has no attribute user on middleware function

Tags: django, url, django-urls, django-users, django-middleware

I have the following middleware function:

```
class LastVisitMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            customer = get_customer(request)
            Customer.objects.filter(pk=customer.pk).update(last_visit=now())
        return response
```

My middleware entries look like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'my.middleware.LastVisitMiddleware',

)
```

My url looks like:

```
url(r'^dashboard/$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

When I go to urls that have a forward slash the page loads normally. When I omit the forward slash I get the error:

> WSGIRequest object has no attribute user

When I remove the middleware I have no issues whether I use the forward slash or not.

How can I prevent from throwing this error with or without a forward slash?

Answer (score 4):

I know that Django redirects any urls without the trailing `/`, so `/home` to `/home/`, but I am not sure when Django does this redirection (apparently after it has run the middleware?). One way to get around this is to check if the `user` object has been set;

```
if hasattr(request, 'user') and request.user.is_authenticated():
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: It looks like you're correct; the redirection will happen before the AuthenticationMiddleware is run, by default. I was just encountering the same issue when running a request without a trailing slash, and adding the trailing slash fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> During the response phases (process_response() and process_exception() middleware), the classes are applied in reverse order, from the bottom up

similar question:

[Django: WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user' on some pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223597/django-wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-user-on-some-pages)